# How do I apply active class to navbar using angular-ui-utils?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I am a rank beginner with angularJS and I'm developing the ui for a single-page app in angularJS using node/bower/grunt and I have installed angular-ui-bootstrap and the route and event utils from angular-ui-utils.
I've used `ng-class={active:$uiRoute}` on the menu items but when a menu item is selected the active class is not applied...does `$uiRoute` handle this or do I need to code it separately?

Apologies for asking a dumb question...
Here is the code:

```
`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ui-route="/" ng-class="{active:$uiRoute}"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
    <li ui-route="/about" ng-class="{active:$uiRoute}"><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
    <li ui-route="/other" ng-class="{active:$uiRoute}"><a href="#/other">Other</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
...
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-utils/modules/route/route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-utils/modules/event/event.js"></script>`
```

And

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngResource','ui.bootstrap'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/about', {
      templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
      controller: 'AboutCtrl'
  })
  .when('/other', {
    templateUrl: 'views/other.html',
    controller: 'OtherCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
})
```

Comment: You need to add `ui.utils' in `angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngResource','ui.bootstrap'])`

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the [ui-utils docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils), it appears you have not injected the module dependency. Change your `myApp` to inject `ui.utils`

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngResource',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.utils'
])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/about', {
      templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
      controller: 'AboutCtrl'
  })
  .when('/other', {
    templateUrl: 'views/other.html',
    controller: 'OtherCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add ng-class="{'active':isActive('/about')}"

.run([ '$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location, ) {
    $rootScope.isActive = function(path) {
         if ($location.path() && $location.path().substring(0, path.length) == path) {
            return true;
         }
         return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you tu use UI router with named states.

Your router will looks like :

```
angular
  .module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(($stateProvider, urlRouterProvider) => {
    $stateProvider
      .state('index', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
      })
      .state('index.about', {
        url: 'about/'
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  });
```

and you will be able to user ui-sref-active directive in your template like :

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ui-sref-active="{ 'active': 'index' }">
      <a href="" ui-sref="index">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active="{ 'active': 'index.about' }">
      <a href="" ui-sref="index.about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```